# Mediawiki cross-page data access

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

Perhaps I'm going a bit overboard here, but I'm looking for a way to access data on a page of my Mediawiki install (call it Page1) and use that data on a second page (call it Page2).  I know I can simply transclude the data, but I'm looking (I think) for a little more than that.

Basically, I'd like to get the data from Page1 and parse it in such a way that I can make it display nicely on Page2.

For a more specific example:  I use Lingo to process on my glossary page (called Glossary), but I don't like the way the glossary displays.  Furthermore, I'd like to be able to add definitions willy nilly without having to worry about alphabetizing them.

My desire is to parse the data in Glossary, and then show it formatted and alphabetized (as desired) in a separate page.

I figure that I can always write an extension that does this for me, but does something like this already exist?  Is this something that is included in Semantic Wiki?

Comment: Have you checked out Semantic MediaWiki?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in SemanticMediaWiki. For an example of an advanced terminology wiki based on SemanticMediaWiki, see http://tieteentermipankki.fi/

As for Lingo, its markup appears to be very simplistic: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lingo#Usage But it allows transclusion, so you can just define each term on its own page, then transclude all the pages in your Terminology page, then transclude them in a different way and wrapped in all the formatting you desire.

Or any variation of the concept, possibly using templates with Lua modules if you need advanced and/or repetitive formatting.